# Capturing all frames with VLC scene-filter

Tags: video, vlc, video-encoding, cvlc

I'm attempting to use VLC's `scene-filter` to extract *all* frames from an `mp4` video. The video in question runs at `25fps`, and is precisely `38s` long.

In the command line, I ran with options:

`--video-filter = scene --start-time = 0 --stop-time = 35 --scene-ratio = 1`

I understood (?) that the scene ratio is the ratio of frames taken from total frames (that is, a ratio of `3` means `1/3` frames are saved). However, of the `~900` frames I'm expecting, I get only about `500` of them.

I've tried using `25`, `-1`, and the default `scene-ratio` values, to no avail.

What am I doing wrong? The `VLC` docs aren't very clear about this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I will try to know more from here.

If you just want to extract frames, then i can tell you other methods like using python.
I also checked by extracting frames using vlc, and it gave me error for each frame like this

`[00007fd7d8005430] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 40 ms)`

To get this error you just have to add `-v` in the end of your code. `-vv` for more detailed output.
so it should look like this:

```
cvlc video.mp4 --video-filter scene --start-time 0 --stop-time 20 --scene-ratio 1 --scene-path Downloads/video -v
```

and I don't know how to solve that. I would suggest using python to extract all frames. If you specifically want answer for this problem then just comment below, I will delete the answer. And if you are ok with python solution then i will update answer with python code.